# Elementary OS theme in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, elementary-theme, greybird

I'm not sure if I am allowed to ask this in this forum, but I've been looking for this theme forever and I can't seem to find it.

I would like to have the Elementary OS theme on my Xubuntu. I have Greybird theme installed, which is very similiar. But I would like to have the arrows like EOS. Does anyone know how to get the same theme or how to replace the arrow instead of the + ?

I'm attaching a photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGF5.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at xfce-look.org ?

Answer (score 3):

I end up creating my own theme after all.

[Elementary Freya Theme | XfceLook](https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1016059/)

Feel free to use it.

Comment: The link is broken: June 2020

Answer (score 0):

Getting the elementary os theme...
In A terminal (Ctl + Alt + T)

First get the ppa for Elementary:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable && sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the theme:

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-icon-theme
```

Comment: I hope this helped you!! Please remember to click the ChecK MarK if this help you install you icon theme!